# Can a Virtualbox guest use graphic acceleration?

Tags: virtualbox

With Ubuntu 18.10 as host and Virtualbox 6.0.2, I have installed Windows 10 as a guest OS. I have a NVIDIA GTX graphics card. I wish to use Sketchup and other graphics-intensive applications on the Windows guest, but the NVIDIA driver will not install on the VB guest. I have installed Oracle VM Virtualbox Extension Pack.

The error message says:

> This NVIDIA graphics driver is not compatible with this version of
>   Windows. This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics
>   hardware.

Is it currently possible to use a Virtualbox guest OS with full graphics card capability?

Comment: It seems off-topic. Maybe related https://superuser.com/questions/779070/use-nvidia-gpu-from-virtualbox?rq=1 https://superuser.com/questions/1291482/how-to-use-geforce-gtx-1050-in-virtualbox